# Add a fork association between two repositories in Microsoft DevOps

Tags: git, azure-devops, fork

Without giving you the entire back-story, we are migrating all our repositories to DevOps.

Two repositories we have imported were forked prior to the import (a long time ago) i.e. they share history. I need to be able to add the fork relationship/association in DevOps so that I can setup pull requests between them. If I can't do this I can only think that I will need to rebuild one of the repositories commit by commit.

Does anyone know how I can add the fork relationship between two repositories in DevOps? Or have any other suggestions?

Comment: Are both repositories in DevOps? Are they in the same organization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "commit by commit", but you should be able to do something like this:

- Import first repo
- Fork it on Azure DevOps (only fork master branch, loose everything else)
- Clone the fork
- Pull everything you have in your original repo by adding another remote (git remote add oldstuff )
- Do something like "git push --all origin"

Details depend on what and how many branches you want to migrate over

Comment: Hi Georgy, that is perfect and makes total sense. I was not thinking clearly yesterday and had only gone half-way down that path. I just tried it out and worked perfectly. Thanks!